Are PowerBASIC variables case-sensitive?
I'm working on porting some old code written in PowerBASIC and compiled by the PowerBASIC Console Compiler.
I don't actually have access to a working PBCC myself, only some compiled artifacts to assist with regression testing the ported code.
In the source there is a variable recur which is defined and then never used, and a variable RECUR which is used but never defined, leading me to believe that the compiler may be case-insensitive for variables.
Can anyone confirm this?
The only reasonable reference that I've found for assisting me with this is this reference, and it doesn't mention anything about this detail, or at the very least I couldn't find it.

Just discovered this forum; will peruse it to look for an answer or drop a line there. If I come up with an answer I'll come back here.

That website links to this help documentation, although it doesn't seem to load. PBCC6 is the version my artifacts were compiled with.

According to a post on the PowerBASIC forums, it is not case-sensitive, so the variables would be the same.

If you have been coding in BASIC for a very long time without using other languages you will most probably continue to use case insensitive keywords and API names but be careful, in the future this will come back to bite you (not BYTE you) as Windows functions (APIs), constants, structures and the like are all case sensitive.
Other languages and future BASIC variants are more than likely to require case sensitive keywords as it dramatically extends the naming range,
PTR
Ptr
ptr
in BASIC all mean the same thing but it excludes you from using any variant form.

